# Changing appearance of RecyclerView row on interact?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

In my bindRow method of my RecyclerView adapter I am checking to see if an EditText has been modified such that its value falls below 100. If so, I change the color of the text to red.

However the text does not update immediately unless I rotate the screen.

How do I get it to change the color immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, this isn't the place where I would be doing this. I have had a similar concern where the ViewHolders in my Adapter weren't accurate - and then rotating the screen 'fixed' it.

My solution involved updating my Adapter's data List<> and then calling [swapAdapter(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#swapAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter,%20boolean))